# knockout mapping performance issue

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Knockout.js incredibly slow under semi-large datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709374/knockout-js-incredibly-slow-under-semi-large-datasets)

I have the following event in my model which works fine if I only have a handful of records but if I get a couple of dozen records, IE compains that my scripts are running too slow.

```
    self.getTrades = function () {

    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: "/_vti_bin/DBOrderService/DBOrderService.svc/GetTradesByDateSource?format=json&traddate=" + self.selectedDate() + "&source=" + self.selectedSource(),
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data.requeststatus.code === 1) {
                var statusId = SP.UI.Status.addStatus(data.requeststatus.message);
                SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(statusId, 'red');
                return;
            }
           debugger;
           ko.mapping.fromJS({ trades: data.trades }, mappings, self); //too slow, events are firing as items are added
            self.selectedTrade(null);
        },
        error: ajaxError
    });
};
```

I think its because mapping is firing change notifications for each row as its added, so i want to copy the  new rows 'in bulk' to my Model.

I tried

```
 var temptrades = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.trades, mappings);
 self.trades=temptrades();
```

and

```
self.trades(temtrades);
```

and

```
self.trades(temptrades();
```

But they all just breajk my model. 
Whats the right way to copy an observable array created by the ko.mapping into my Model all at once. Is there and option on ko.mapping that will prevent firing events until the end?

Comment: You should review your past questions for acceptable answers.

Answer (score 5):

```
   ko.mapping.fromJS({ trades: data.trades }, mappings, self); //too slow, events are firing as items are added
```

You're exactly right. Events are firing as items are added

Please see: [Knockout.js Performance Gotcha #2 - Manipulating observableArrays](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html)

> A better pattern is to get a reference to our underlying array, push to it, then call .valueHasMutated(). Now, our subscribers will only receive one notification indicating that the array has changed.

Also, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9709431/109941).

Splitting up the [mapping] and [observable array update] into two steps may help things.