# Knockout loading data very slowly

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, knockout.js

I am calling WCF service to load data via jquery ajax calls. WCF service returns data very fast but knockout is loading that data very slowy. Below is my call to wcf service using jquery ajax

```
 function loadData(id) {
        var input =
            {
                Id: id
            };


        $.ajax({
            url: "../Service/Table/TableData",
            type: "PUT",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            processData: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(input),
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                alert(errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (allData) {
                var mappedData= $.map(allData, function (item) {

                    return new TableData(item);
                });
                self.TableDataList(mappedData);



            }
        });

    }
```

Below is my view

```
<div  style="overflow: hidden;margin-top: 30px;margin-left: 10px;float:left;" >

            <table style="width: 100%" >

                <colgroup>
                    <col   />
                    <col  />

                    <col/>
                </colgroup>

                <thead><tr>

                           <th style="padding: 0px">Id </th>
                           <th style="padding: 0px">Name</th>

                       </tr>

                </thead>

            </table>
            <div style="overflow: auto;height: 490px;">
                <table id ="Table1" class="Hover" style="width: 100%;" >
                    <colgroup>
                        <col   style="width: 20px"/>
                        <col style="width: 80px"/>

                        <col/>
                    </colgroup>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: TableDataList">

                        <tr>

                            <td style="padding: 0px;text-align: left" data-bind="text: Id"  ></td>
                            <td style="padding: 0px;" data-bind="text: Name "></td>

                        </tr>   


                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

I am loading about 20000 records and it takes 2 min to load page. How to avoid this?

**UPDATE1**

Will using jquery template solve the issue or need to do paging?

**UPDATE2**

Here is my code for TableData class

```
 function TableData (data) {
        this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
        this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        this.LastName = ko.observable(data.LastName );
        this.DateOfBirth = ko.observable(data.DateOfBirth );
        this.Age= ko.observable(data.Age);


    }
```

Comment: The obvious fix is to not load 20000 record, but do server side paging...

Comment: @nemesv but server is returning data very quickly. Its only this knockout loading it very slowly

Comment: @Happy it will obviously be slow as it's going to be a heavy operation looping through 20000 records and creating elements. Obvious solution would be to implement paging (server and/or client side)

Comment: cant understand why its downvoted

Answer (score 3):

Paging is the best solution for this as @nemesv. Processing 20000 records on client side will have its own cost in terms of performance while rendering the content on page so it's not knockout framework which is performing slow. So you can also use on demand loading "onScreenscroll" or something like that to get your page speedup.

Comment: What will you say about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709374/knockout-js-incredibly-slow-under-semi-large-datasets  But i cant understand what to use

Comment: Have you tried sending the less no. of records to your page??

Answer (score 1):

Can we see the code of TableData class ?
I think you create a lot of observables for each property in this class.

As the view does't contain any input field I guess you don't want modify  the data.

That's what I thought. TableData class is what slow down your code.
The TableData class is useless because you don't have any computed in it.
And because you don't want to modify the data,  you don't need observables for TableData properties.

Try to replace the success function by this one.

```
success: function (allData) {
    self.TableDataList(allData);
}
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yx5zG/)

Comment: If i use your code i get error as Property 'Id' of object #<Object> is not a function

Comment: This is the right fix if you need to load all 20K records. You don't need $.map at all (creating 20K x 5 = 100K observable properties), just load the results straight into the array object.

Comment: @ChrisDixon if i use code mentioned by Damien i get If i use your code i get error as Property 'Id' of object #<Object> is not a function

Comment: Somewhere in the view or view model you wrote "Id()". Replace it by "Id". You have to do this correction for all the properties.

Comment: ^^ That'll be what's happening.

Comment: @ChrisDixon so what should i do Chris? Please help me

Comment: I updated my post to add a fiddle.
Please modify it to reproduce the problem and I will fix it.

Comment: @Damien can you invite me for chat?

Comment: @Damien sorry the error i pasted was not in my view but in my viewmodel. I fixed it and i am loading data. But still it takes same amount of time as before