# Knockout taking too much time to apply bindings on a 10 records data set

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I got a 10 record data set sent from server and into my model so far good every thing is running smooth but it takes nearly 10 seconds when it hits the ko.applyBindings() code line.

Please check my jsfiddle for a code example:
[http://jsfiddle.net/j772E/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/j772E/)

Any help would be great i need to know what could be making it take that long i thought it was Entity Framework but after testing that thought got ruled out.

Thanks!

Also here's the Exact Code i Wrote:

**JS**

```
var Model = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.Maintenance = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.GroupUser = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.Assign = function (data, event) {
        var userID = $("#users" + data.ID()).val();
        var userName = $("#users" + data.ID() + " option:selected").text();
        if (userID != "-1") {
            if (data.AssignedTo() == null) {
                var RequestAssign = {
                    MaintenanceID: data.ID(),
                    UserID: userID,
                    MaintenanceType: data.Type()
                };
                $.post("../../Maintenance/AssignRequsetToUser", RequestAssign, function () {
                    data.AssignedTo(userName);
                    if (data.Type() == "Request") {
                        var CurrentDate = new Date();
                        data.StartDate(CurrentDate.getDay() + "/" + CurrentDate.getMonth() + "/" + CurrentDate.getFullYear());
                    }
                    $("#users" + data.ID()).val("-1");
                });
            }
            else {
                var RequestAssign = {
                    AssignID: data.AssignID(),
                    UserID: userID,
                    MaintenanceID: data.ID()
                };
                $.post("../../Maintenance/UpdateAssignRequsetToUser", RequestAssign, function () {
                    $.get("../../Maintenance/GetFullMaintenanceRecords", function () {
                        data.AssignedTo(userName);
                        $("#users" + data.ID()).val("-1");
                    });
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Please Select a User First!");
        }
    };

    self.CurrentPage = ko.observable(0);

    self.Pages = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.ChangePage = function (data, event) {
        $(".pagination li").removeClass("active disabled");
        self.CurrentPage(data);
    };

    self.checkCurrentPage = function (data) {
        if (self.CurrentPage() == data) {
            return "active disabled";
        }
    };
};

var Maintenance = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = ko.observable();
    self.StartDate = ko.observable();
    self.EndDate = ko.observable();
    self.Comment = ko.observable();
    self.Type = ko.observable();
    self.AssignedTo = ko.observable();
    self.AssignID = ko.observable();
};

var CreateMaintenance = function (data) {
    var _maintenance = new Maintenance();
    _maintenance.ID(data.ID);
    _maintenance.StartDate(data.StartDate);
    _maintenance.EndDate(data.EndDate);
    _maintenance.Comment(data.Comment);
    _maintenance.Type(data.Type);
    _maintenance.AssignedTo(data.AssignedTo);
    _maintenance.AssignID(data.AssignID);

    return _maintenance;
};

var GroupUser = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = undefined;
    self.ID = undefined;
};

var CreateGroupUser = function (name, id) {
    var _groupuser = new GroupUser();
    _groupuser.Name = name;
    _groupuser.ID = id;

    return _groupuser;
};

var IntializeEvents = function () {
    $(".text-danger").tooltip();
    $(".text-success").tooltip();
};

var GetMaintenance = function () {
    $.get("../../Maintenance/GetFullMaintenanceRecords", OnGetSuccess);
};

var OnGetUsersSuccess = function (data) {
    var result = JSON.parse(data);

    result.forEach(function (obj) {
        ModelInstance.GroupUser.push(CreateGroupUser(obj.Name_en, obj.id));
    });

    ko.applyBindings(ModelInstance);

    IntializeEvents();
};

function Chunk(Arr, ChunkSize) {
    var Set = [];

    var PageCount = 0;

    for (var Page = 0; Page < Arr.length; Page += ChunkSize) {
        var TempArr = Arr.slice(Page, Page + ChunkSize);

        var ObservableItemArr = [];

        TempArr.forEach(function (obj) {
            ObservableItemArr.push(CreateMaintenance(obj));
        });

        Set.push(ko.observableArray(ObservableItemArr));

        ModelInstance.Pages.push(PageCount);

        PageCount++;
    }

    return Set;
}

var OnGetSuccess = function (data) {
    var result = JSON.parse(data);

    ModelInstance.Maintenance(Chunk(result, 10));

    $.get("../../Maintenance/FillDropUsers", OnGetUsersSuccess);
};

var ModelInstance = new Model();

$(document).ready(function () {
    GetMaintenance();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<section data-bind="foreach: Pages">
        <article data-bind="visible: $root.CurrentPage() == $data">
            <table style="margin-bottom: 0" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>Start Date</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span>End Date</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Maintenance Status</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Type</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Assign Status</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Assign</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Parts Replaced</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.Maintenance()[$data]">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text: StartDate"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: EndDate"></td>
                        <td>
                            <span style="cursor: pointer;" data-bind="visible: StartDate() == '', text: 'Waiting'" class="text-warning"></span>
                            <span style="cursor: pointer;" data-bind="visible: StartDate() != '' && EndDate() == '', text: 'Pending'" class="text-success"></span>
                            <span style="cursor: pointer;" data-bind="visible: EndDate() != '', text: 'Closed'" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td data-bind="text: Type"></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 24px;">
                            <span style="cursor: pointer;" data-bind="visible: AssignedTo() == null, attr: { title: 'Not Assigned' }" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="text-danger">●</span>
                            <span style="cursor: pointer;" data-bind="visible: AssignedTo() != null, attr: { title: AssignedTo(), 'data-original-title': AssignedTo() }" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="text-success">●</span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">
                            <select style="width: 165px;" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="attr: { id: 'users' + ID() }">
                                <option value="-1">-- Select --</option>
                                <!-- ko foreach: $root.GroupUser -->
                                <option data-bind="value: ID, text: Name"></option>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </select>
                            <button style="width: 110px;" data-bind="click: $root.Assign" class="btn btn-warning">Assign</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary form-control" href="#" target="_blank" data-bind="attr: { href: 'GetAllPartsByMaintenance_ID/' + ID() }">View Parts</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </article>
    </section>
    <ul class="pagination" data-bind="foreach: Pages">
        <li data-bind="attr: { id: 'Page' + $index(), 'class': $root.checkCurrentPage($data) }, click: $root.ChangePage"><a href="#" data-bind="    text: $data"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Page loads fast in last Chrome. What browser do you use?

Comment: Tested on all 3 major browsers with latest versions (Chrome, Firefox, Opera) Same behavior

Comment: I added some logs, it loads in less than a second on my machine http://jsfiddle.net/j772E/1/

Comment: There is not as much data in the drop down in my example provided on jsfiddle maybe that's the problem?!!

Comment: KO can be slow when building a large observableArray with each item bound to something in the DOM. This question will give you some good tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709374/knockout-js-incredibly-slow-under-semi-large-datasets/24914377#24914377