# foreach large select slowing down knockoutjs databinding

Tags: optimization, knockout.js

**My Problem**

I have a table that loads the **same select** that has hundreds of options for every data item retrieved.  I retrieve the data for the select and store it in a JavaScript variable prior to the data-binding. The problem is that because there are so many options, the options take 10+ seconds to populate a data set with 200+ items.

**What I have done to determine this was the problem**

I have found by removing the selects the data-binding runs very quickly so I'm certain that this is my issue.

**My Question**

What else can I do to speed this process up?

**My Implementation**

```
<table id="reportList">
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: reportList'>
       <tr>
          <td>
              <select class="itemSelect" data-bind="options: $root.selectItemIDOptions,
                                                    value:ItemID, optionsValue: 'ItemID',
                                                    optionsText: 'SupplierItemID',
                                                    optionsCaption: 'Select Item'"  />

          </td>
          <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
       </tr>
```

My View Model

```
function ReportViewModel(reportData) {

  //GlobalItemList already has all of the select options at this point ready for databinding
  self.selectItemIDOptions = GlobalItemList;
  self.reportList = ko.observableArray();
  var Shrinkage = reportData.ShrinkageList;
  var rowArr = self.reportList();
  for (var i = 0; i < Shrinkage.length; i++) {
    rowArr.push(new ReportRow(Shrinkage[i].ItemID, Shrinkage[i].Description);
  }

   self.reportList.valueHasMutated();
}
```

Row class

```
function ReportRow(ItemID, Description) {

  var self = this;
  self.ItemID = ko.observable(ItemID);
  self.Description = ko.observable(Description);
}
```

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709374/knockout-js-incredibly-slow-under-semi-large-datasets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to not try and fix or debug Knockout in regards to large data sets, but instead refactor the data you are sending.

What if you took ~10 fields per record (instead of 100) for the first data call and then provide a "Get Details" link for a user to retrieve the other 90 fields on a row by row basis.

That would load the original list very quickly and each subsequent call for more detail would also be fast.