# Browser freezes while appending data to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, knockout.js

Here's the scenario. I've built a grid with min. 1 to max. 132 columns with more than 10k rows. I am using `knockout` for data binding. The data is fetched by `$.ajax` function of `jquery`. On first call it fetches 100 rows and 100 rows on each scroll. If less than 100 it returns all the rows.

The browser does not freeze when `ajax` is call made but the browser freezes after `ajax` call. So once we've data at client side, it binds to the `table`. The browser freezes for a second or two while appending rows with data to the table.

```
    function demoData(args){
    var self = this;
    self.dataList = ko.observableArray();
    self.fillData = function () {
    self.tableListPager = new ScrollPagerForAccordian($("#tblGrid"), 40, self.fillDetailData);
    $.ajax({ //api call });
    self.loadDetailData(data);
    }

    self.fillDetailData = function (pageNo) {
    $.ajax({ //api call });
    }

self.loadDetailData = function (res) {
self.dataList.push();
}

    function ScrollPagerForAccordian(el, recHeight, callback) {
    }
```

Even I tried to put `self.loadDetailData(data)` in web worker but still the browser freezes.

**Update:**
Is there any way to load next 100 rows in background and append it without freezing a browser on a scroll ???

**Update-2**

Please find below `<tbody>` structure:

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: dataList">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: rowValues()">
        <td data-bind="style :{ width :colwidth + 'em' , 'min-width' :colwidth + 'em' , 'max-width' :colwidth + 'em'  }">
            <!-- ko if: displayFlag == true -->
                <!-- ko if: flagData  == false -->
                        rendering div
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: flagData  == true -->
                        rendering another div
                <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: displayFlag == false -->
                        rendering another div
            <!-- /ko -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

**How do I prevent browser freezing in such a case ???**

I am using `Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m` and have to resolve this issue for `chrome` only as the view will be displayed in `awsomium` control.

Comment: Browser UIs are single threaded, so anytime the javascript is doing work, the UI will freeze.  132 columns with up to 10k rows is a LOT of data to be displaying on the screen in one go, and each rendering of the table will take time.  I would suggest seeing if you can redesign it so as you scroll down, the data above the page is no longer rendered, or use some sort of pagination on your table.

Comment: @JamesThorpe - Yes I've implemented that once data is rendered on a page, it won't be rendered again on a scroll. And each time 100 rows are appended. The browser freezes while appending these new rows to a table. And we are not allowed to implement pagination for this grid.

Comment: Even if it's only rendering these extra rows, on the assumption you're using a `<table>` to do so, the browser will be checking the rest of the page for possibly adjusting column widths etc.  IE used to be (probably still is) notoriously slow for doing this kind of thing.

Comment: @JamesThorpe - I've to resolve this only on `chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m`. And is there any way to ignore column adjusting each time ???

Comment: Try reducing the rows to 50 instead of 100 ... since for each row you're fetching 132 columns... loading/appending all these on front-end will take time

Comment: @Haridarshan - reducing number of rows is not a solution. It's like a patch/fix. 100 rows is the requirement.

Comment: @ChakoDesai Check this out... This might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9723763/2324206

Comment: @Haridarshan - still the same problem of browser freeze. Tried with template and with `ko.utils.arrayMap` as well.

Comment: @ChakoDesai Since you're loading data on scroll try **knockout MVC BigData** 
http://knockoutmvc.com/BigData

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65770/discussion-between-chako-desai-and-haridarshan).

Comment: if the browser is freezed means i believe your having something like `async:false` in your ajax call .

Comment: @supercool - you can read latest discussion in chat. And there is no `async:false` in ajax call.