# Grid value not updating on changing dropdown in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Please find the updated fiddle in the comment section.

I have provided the HTML code and the ViewModel. On changing the value in drop down I want the pip value in grid to be updated. The pip value is getting calculated for new drop down value but the return is not able to bind the value to grid.

Comment: This is the updated fiddle which works fine http://jsfiddle.net/Kapil_B/vz3r0bs3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make `seats` change in the UI on `dropdownAValue` change you need to declare empty observable array first:

```
self.seats = ko.observableArray();
```

And update it in the subscribe function instead of creating new `observableArray` every time:

```
self.seats([new PipCalculation(self.rates[0], self.rates[0].price, self.rates, self.newLot[0],currentlotvalue) ]);
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ue83s4t/7/)

Comment: Yes it works(yes we need to declare first) but any reason why we doing `self.seats([new xyz()])` instead of `self.seats.push(new xyz())` . The second way doesn't show any error but grid wont update .

Comment: These are different `Push` adds values to the array, while `self.seats([new xyz()])` replaces old values with new one. Both should work but you should be aware of the performance issues, see this article http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

Comment: @supercool Your code works as expected it adds values to the end of the `seats` array. In order to replace array values you have following options:
1. Clear array and push items to it `self.seats([])`, `self.seats.push(`. It's not a best option, because it will force UI to update each time you push the value, so it's slow.
2. Create the temporary flat array of values and update `seats` with it. See [Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ue83s4t/7/)

Comment: thanks man +1 for being so clear . actually deleted my comment i.e i made it to work & yes by clearing and then pushing .

Comment: Thanks Max it worked..I had the alert before returning the value and it was reflecting updated value but the HTML was not getting updated.

Now I understand what was missing.

Appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello Max here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Kapil_B/g2z0kwzr/2/, where I am trying to update the pip value on changing the rates. So in formattedPrice2, I am able to get the updated price but the price1 is not getting updated value.

Can you please tell me the reason why the price1 value is not getting updated?

Answer (score 1):

well my answer will be addition to what `Max Brodin` has given .

We can further normalize you code by doing something like this

**View model:**

```
    self.dropdownAValue = ko.observable(0.1);

    self.seats = ko.observableArray([]);

    var newItems = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.rates,function(item){
    return new PipCalculation(item, item.price, self.rates, self.newLot[0], self.dropdownAValue)
    });
    self.seats(newItems);

    //computed code
    self.formattedPrice2 = ko.computed(function() {
           //alert("hi");
            var cur = self.rate().pair;
            //var price = self.rate().price;
            //alert(self.myQuote());
            var price = self.myQuote();
            var pip = 1;
            var lot1 =currentlotvalue().lotSize;
```

Working fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/5ue83s4t/8/)

**Things to do :**

- There is no need to additionally write a subscribe for subscribing drop-down changes . All you need to do is send right `DD` value instance further in your case .
- There is a performance hit as your are  filling observablearray inside DD subscribe i.e every-time dropdown changes . That can be avoided by doing like i mentioned above.
- Rather pushing into Observable array push into a normal array and the later using that array (performance improved)  - max mentioned in his comments

*There is a other way to do this like (i done previously like this)*

```
self.seats([]); 
var mutatedArray = self.seats();
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.rates,function(item){
mutatedArray.push(new PipCalculation(item, item.price, self.rates, self.newLot[0],self.dropdownAValue));  // push to the array(normal array)  
});  
 self.seats.valueHasMutated();
```

For more on this do refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709374/knockout-js-incredibly-slow-under-semi-large-datasets?noredirect=1#comment42982582_9709374) .