# Not able to push values into an observavblearray

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I cannot understand why this small code is not working properly.Please help!
All i try is to push textbox values into an array and then then display it back using a binding.
HTML code is :

```
<div>
Add Task:<input type="text"  placeholder="abcd" data-bind="value:viewModel.newTask"/>
    <input type="button" value="add"  data-bind="click:viewModel.addTask" />
</div>

<div data-bind="foreach:viewModel.tasks" ></div>
```

js script is:

```
var viewModel = function (items) {
var self = this;

self.newTask = ko.observable();
self.tasks = ko.observableArray(items);

self.addTask = function () {
    self.tasks().push(self.newTask());
    self.newTask(" ");

} 

ko.applyBindings(viewModel(["alpha","beta","gamma"]));
}
```

i tried it in JSFiddle also:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rakz_1221/m3rwupmz/1/

Comment: You haven't included Knockout.JS in your JSFiddle demo.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you haven't included KnockoutJS in your JSFiddle demo, so your demo will not work anyway.

<s>The problem you have is that you're calling `tasks.push`. `tasks` itself isn't an array. `tasks` is a function - a Knockout Observable. In order to push values into it, we need to execute this function by calling `tasks().push()` instead.</s>

As James Thrope has commented, you can in fact call `tasks.push`, sorry about that!

Finally, your `ko.applyBindings(...)` is never being called as it's contained within your `viewModel` function - which you're not calling at any point.

I strongly advise you to go through KnockoutJS's very own interactive tutorial available at http://learn.knockoutjs.com.

Comment: [`observableArray`s have a `.push` method](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#pop-push-shift-unshift-reverse-sort-splice) - indeed if you call `push` on the underlying array, knockout won't actually see the change unless you manually trigger notifications afterwards

Comment: @JamesThorpe TIL! I've always been following that up with a `valueHasMutated` - I guess I'll go through my latest project and replace all instances of that!

Comment: actually no need to fallow up with `valuHasMuatated` if you are really pushing to observableArray (internally it calls valuHasMuated) . but i do something like i make observableArray flat and i will push to it later i call valueHasMuated on that . you can fallow up what i'm saying from my answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709374/knockout-js-incredibly-slow-under-semi-large-datasets/27252722#27252722