# KnockoutJS renders whole tables rows costing of observables array after I add new elements

Tags: javascript, performance, knockout.js

Basically I do have a datatable where I render rows with knockout 'foreach'.
Initial render will display 100 rows and there is a button which will request next 100 rows from the server via ajax call on click. 
Because the table is quite large(many columns) with many observable it takes long time to render. 
First 100 rows are still okay, but if I want to show more it takes really long time especially when it reaches e.g 1000 rows.

Tired to figure out why this is happening and I found out when I add new rows in **observalbeArray** which contains all the rows, the UI renders all the rows starting with first one all the time. My expectation was to see that the grid is updated with only the new added rows.

[image]

dataSource it is a **pureComputed**

[image]

***UPDATE***: this is how I add next 100 rows

```
 result.data.TotalResults = result.data.DataRows.length + viewmodel.dataSource().length;
 viewmodel.ds.pushAll(result.data.DataRows);
```

Comment: Related question that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709374/knockout-js-incredibly-slow-under-semi-large-datasets

Comment: How are you adding the next 100 to the array? Show some code

Comment: The question Shameen linked in turn links to the following article, which has a section called "pushing items to an observableArray" which might be relevant to your situtation. http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

Comment: I've made the mistake before of thinking ko.utils.arrayPushAll would be smart enough to do exactly as that article suggests, but sadly it's just a loop. [Source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/utils.js)

Comment: Tried this method:  www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html It didn't work, same problem so far

Answer (score 0):

if you want `ko` to only render new rows, you should keep the original `observableArray` and only use `push` to add new rows.

below is the example how to use

```js
const vm = {
  data: ko.observableArray([])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

// reference of observable data
var _data = vm.data();

setTimeout(() => {
  const ajaxData = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  _data.push(...ajaxData);
  vm.data.valueHasMutated();
}, 100);


setTimeout(() => {
  // midify already rendered <li> to see if it gets re-rendered by ko  
  const firstLi = document.querySelector('ul > li');
  firstLi.innerText = 'modified';
  firstLi.style.color = 'red';
}, 1000);


setTimeout(() => {
  var ajaxData2 = ['four', 'five'];
  _data.push(...ajaxData2);
  vm.data.valueHasMutated();
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: data">
  <li data-bind="text: $data">
</ul>
```